# Relay. Accessing data of sibling component

Tags: relayjs

Playing with Relay I got problems with accessing data. I was trying to reproduce the issues with official Todo example of the Relay project. Please consider gist in order to change Todo example. 
[here](https://gist.github.com/Efimster/886650d04f141e50c08d)

Here are the questions:

1. Why Summary component cant get access to sibling (viewer) component data?
2. What the reason for "queries must have exactly one field"? GraphQL doesn't have such limitations I believe.
3. Why I got Invariant Violation: Relay(TodoApp).getFragment(): `summary` is not a valid fragment name ?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

1. Whatever data `Summary` wants to use from viewer has to be delclared as GraphQL in the `Summary` container, and composed all the way down to the root of the application.

   ```js
   class Summary extends React.Component {
     render() {
       return <span>{this.props.viewer.bar}</span>;
     }
   }
   export default Relay.createContainer(Summary, {
     fragments: {
       viewer: () => Relay.QL`
         fragment on Viewer {
           bar
         }
       `,
     },
   });

   class TodoApp extends React.Component {
     render() {
       return <Summary viewer={this.props.viewer} />;
     }
   }
   export default Relay.createContainer(TodoApp, {
     fragments: {
       viewer: () => Relay.QL`
         fragment on Viewer {
           foo
           ${Summary.getFragment('viewer')}
         }
       `,
     },
   });
   ```

   Note that the `foo` field will *not* be available inside `Summary`. We mask it out since `Summary` didn't ask for it.
2. You can have multiple queries in a `Relay.Route`, but only one root field per query. We need this one-to-one correspondence so that we know which result to assign to which prop.

   ```js
   class MyRoute extends Relay.Route {
     queries: {
       summary: () => Relay.QL`query { summary }`,
       viewer: () => Relay.QL`query { viewer }`,
     },
     /* ... */
   }
   ```
3. You need to compose the summary fragment all the way down to the root of the application, making it available on `TodoApp`.

   ```js
   export default Relay.createContainer(TodoApp, {
     fragments: {
       summary: () => Relay.QL`
         fragment on Summary {
           ${Summary.getFragment('summary')}
         }
       `,
     },
   });
   ```